# Getting the coordinates from the location I touch the touchscreen

Tags: swift, coordinates, touchscreen

I try to get the coordinates from the location where I hit the touchscreen to do put a specific UIImage at this point.

How can I do this?

Comment: **Another solution is `UITapGestureRecognizer`**, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34130497/8740349

Answer (score 47, accepted):

In a `UIResponder` subclass, such as `UIView`:

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.anyObject()! as UITouch
    let location = touch.locationInView(self)
}
```

This will return a `CGPoint` in view coordinates.

**Updated with Swift 3 syntax**

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self)
}
```

**Updated with Swift 4 syntax**

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
}
```

Comment: And if I want to do it in the ViewController class I get the error 'ViewController' is not convertible to 'UIView' What should I change in the code?

Comment: @Mundi is right, and just to clarify, your location line would look like the following if you are getting the touch location from the view controller and not a UIView subclass:
`let location = touch.locationInView(self.view)`

Comment: could someone update this for Swift 5 and Swift UI, please?

Answer (score 22):

Taking this forward for Swift 3 - I'm using:

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: self)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```

Happy to hear any clearer or more elegant ways to produce the same result

Comment: Thanks for answering. I already got that figured out but I also appreciate the easier solution.

Answer (score 15):

This is work in Swift 2.0

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position :CGPoint = touch.locationInView(view)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Swift 4.0

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: view)
        print(position)
    }
}
```

[source](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/uikit/how-to-find-a-touchs-location-in-a-view-with-locationin)

Answer (score 2):

For SwiftUI I created a new swift file called `HostingController.swift`

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class HostingController: UIHostingController<ContentView> {

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if let touch = touches.first {
            let position = touch.location(in: view)
            print(position)
        }
    }
}
```

Then I changed the following lines of code in the `SceneDelegate.swift`

```
window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

to

```
window.rootViewController = HostingController(rootView: ContentView())
```

SwiftUI is basically wrapped in a ViewController via the UIHostingController. At least thats how I think it is.

I hope this helps!

Greetings krjw

Answer (score 0):

Latest swift4.0, For ViewController

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
if let touch = touches.first {
    let location = touch.location(in: self.view)
    print(location.x)
    print(location.y)
  }
}
```