# how to get tap point (coordinates) in iOS swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to get the coordinates of a touch on the screen, To show a popup menu

*how to use in page view controller*

What am I doing wrong here?

```
  override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
      let position = touch.locationInView(view)
      print(position)
    }
  }
```

Comment: This code works fine, I tested in simulator with iOS 9.1 sdk

Comment: but it's not work for me, it had any deleget or other code for working

Comment: Try this method : http://stackoverflow.com/a/10556526/2286267

Comment: I tried your coding now.It works fine for me.Which xcode are you using?

Comment: Also which iOS version are you using?

Comment: What is not working? Voting to close as off topic

Comment: iOS 9   and xcode 7.0

Comment: Check if `touchesBegan()` is even getting called

Comment: Below my answer is perfectly working for me.

Comment: in a single page this code working fine, but am tring to a page view controller

Comment: Did you check whether the function is being called at all? Insert a `print()` statement **before** the `if let` statement.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In PageViewController,if you want to get pop up

In viewDidLoad:

```
let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "showMoreActions:")
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

Make the page view controller inherit `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` then add:

```
  func showMoreActions(touch: UITapGestureRecognizer) {

        let touchPoint = touch.locationInView(self.view)
        let DynamicView = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(touchPoint.x, touchPoint.y, 100, 100))
        DynamicView.backgroundColor=UIColor.greenColor()
        DynamicView.layer.cornerRadius=25
        DynamicView.layer.borderWidth=2
        self.view.addSubview(DynamicView)

}
```

[UIPageViewController with TouchEvent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788780/uipageviewcontroller-gesture-recognizers)

Comment: And what exactly is the difference?

Comment: I applied above coding in my xcode,it works fine for me.

Comment: I put the break point and it calls every time whenever I touch the view.

Comment: in a page view controller how to impliment this code

Comment: add to viewDidLoad ::  cannot assign a value of type view controller to a value  of type 'UIGesterRecognizerDelegate?

Comment: Did you go through the above link?

Comment: Please tick my answer.

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 5:**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(touchedScreen(touch:)))
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
}

@objc func touchedScreen(touch: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let touchPoint = touch.location(in: self.view)
    print(touchPoint)
}
```