# How to Count the number of times the screen be touched in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, screen, uitouch

How to get the number of times the screen be touched in swift I don't

know which method to use, please help

Comment: Do yo mean number of touches on the screen at the time or number of taps?

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829295/swift-getting-the-coordinates-from-the-location-i-touch-the-touchscreen/34735546#34735546

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is quite simple, just declare a counter at top, `var counter = 0`

then use the function, just type touchesBegan it will show

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    counter++
    print(counter)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lee your answer helped me so much, but I have a question if there's any way to make that counter with swipe gesture .I mean inside  a swipe action function not inside touchesBegan function .
Thanks again :)

Comment: @AhmedAssemMostafa what do you mean by swipe action?

Comment: For buttons actions this method wont call, how to get that?

Comment: @AnilkumariOSdeveloper this is not button action, this is touch/tapped event

Answer (score 0):

Create  static var counter = 0
Counter  should be static variable.

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
counter++
print(counter)
}
```