# How to get touch location when clicking a UIImageView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I want to be able to determine the x,y location where the user clicked a UIImageView in Swift.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829295/getting-the-coordinates-from-the-location-i-touch-the-touchscreen/34735546

Comment: What have you setup so far? Where exactly are you having an issue? Are you using a tap gesture with the image view or something else? Please [edit] your question will all relevant details (do not post comments).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the coordinates from the location I touch the touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26829295/getting-the-coordinates-from-the-location-i-touch-the-touchscreen)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if let touch = touches.first {
        let position = touch.location(in: imageView)
        print(position.x)
        print(position.y)
    }
}
```